# Can GET request message ever return a HTTP status code of 201?

Tags: rest, http, https, http-status-code-403

Can a GET request message ever return a HTTP status code of 201?

Comment: A GET reuest can return any status code you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conforming HTTP server should never do this. `GET` is a safe method, and is not supposed to have any side effects.

`201` means a new resource was created on the server, which really is a side-effect.

So if a `GET` results in a `201`, something is wrong. However, if you are building a client want to know in advance which success codes you *might* get, you should simply support *every* code between 200 and 299 (inclusive) and treat them all as success codes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The API has control over what status code to send.

In practice, the status code is meant to communicate the status of the response - so it’s unlikely that a 201 (“Created”) should be returned from a GET request.

Answer (score -1):

201 - created.

We can return code 201 for GET, but normally we use POST to send some data in server. So I don't think it is good to return 201 for GET